# To find the area of a polygon with infinite sides .

Tags: geometry

**Let P0 be an equilateral triangle of area 10. Each side of P0 is trisected into three segments
of equal length, and the corners of P0 are snipped off, creating a new polygon (in fact, a
hexagon) P1. What is the area of P1? Now repeat the process to P1 – i.e. trisect each side
and snip off the corners – to obtain a new polygon P2. What is the area of P2? Now repeat
this process infinitely to create an object P∞. What can you say about the shape P∞? What
is the area of P∞?**

I have question in the last part of the problem(area of P∞ ) .

*My thought*

After thinking for some time I observed that 3 sides of every polygons we make are in contact with the sides of the triangle (1 side of polygon is in contact with 1 side of a triangle) .

So if we continue the process infinite times then the polygon will eventually turn into a circle with the sides of a triangle touching a point on the circle at 3 different parts . So its basically a *incircle* of the triangle .

Is my thought right ? If no what can the solution of the last part of the problem ?

Source [PROMYS-2023](https://promys-india.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/PROMYS_India_2023_Application.pdf)

Comment: Create a sequence and then do limit to infinity

Comment: The limit curve is definitely not a circle. See [here](https://www.themathdoctors.org/infinitely-truncating-a-triangle/)

Comment: @JeanMarie ahh, I got this . Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprized that the limit set can be placed in correspondence with a family of fractals (Von Koch fractals ?)